# Job chaining on Amazon EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I need to do 2 chained M/R jobs, so I would need to use the output of the first job as input for the second.

How can I achive this on EMR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple jobs as steps. And use S3 to store the intermediate results. The second mapreduce job can read the intermediate results from S3 and continue to finish the work.